# How can I calculate the significance of an acquisition test campaign on Facebook by using chi-squared test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Should I use number of installs and spending or should I use impression and install numbers in Chi-Squared Test (Evan's Awesome A/B Tools)? Here is the link of the results:https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SGYc.jpg  Are the test results significant?